# Linux awk trouble with linebreak into a variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk, printing, echo

I have found many topics but I can't find something matching my exact case..

When I run the following command in my script: `sudo lshw -C disk -short | grep "/dev/"`, my `hdds` var will be set to `/dev/sda 32GB VMware Virtual S /dev/cdrom VMware IDE CDR10`.

And I am able to use awk to be able to remove "/dev/" but I would then add a linebreak with /n so when I would do echo `$hdds` it would show something like this (instead of displaying everything on a single line) :

```
sda 32GB VMware Virtual S
cdrom VMware IDE CDR10
```

I actually managed to do that, but I can't assign that result to my variable.. Only when I am having the output while running the live command.

```
#!/bin/bash

hdds=`sudo lshw -C disk -short | grep "/dev/" | awk '{print $2,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'`
hdd=`echo $hdds | awk '{split($hdds,hdd,"/dev/"); print hdd[2]; print " HEY \n"; print hdd[3]}'`
echo $hdd | awk '{print $hdd;}'
```

Thanks for help!
Currently trying to do that under ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code (missing quotes, deprecated backticks, trying to use shell variables in an awk script, etc.) and idk if when you say you want `echo $myvar` to have the stated value if that's REALLY what you want or if you meant `echo "$myvar"` or `echo "$hdd"` so idk what it's intended to do but it looks like you're trying to convert the output of `sudo lshw -C disk -short` to some other format. If so then please [edit] your question to show the output of `sudo lshw -C disk -short` plus the final output you want given that as input, and explain the transformation.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply and sorry for the way I did formulate my question. As you asked, I did reformulate it differently accordingly to your suggestion. thanks!

Comment: I **really** wish you'd simply show us the output of `sudo lshw -C disk -short` as I requested instead of showing us the contents of "my `hdds` var" after running `sudo lshw -C disk -short | grep "/dev/"` as I strongly suspect the problem is in the way you're calling `echo` to display the contents of your variables but without seeing that original command output it's a guess. I also wish you'd show your final expected output as you have a script that's printing `HEY` but the string `HEY` doesn't appear anywhere in the output you have shown us so idk what the relationship is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that `sudo lshw -C disk -short` already produces multi-line output and the main problem you have is that you're not quoting the argument to `echo` in which case all you need is:

```
hdd=$(sudo lshw -C disk -short | sed -n 's:/dev/::p')
echo "$hdd"
```

but without seeing the output of `sudo lshw -C disk -short` and your expected final output, it's just an untested guess.

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 for info on the quotes and ticks issues in your script.